# Html.Encode does not return anything

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can't get this to work, I want to show a simple list of artist names but always get empty links back.

```
foreach (Artist artist in Model)
{%>
    <a href="gotosomewhere"><% Html.Encode(artist.Name); %></a>
<%}
```

I have debugged it, and I'm certain that Model contains a list of artists.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: do you have any other controls that you request from this same spot, that are being populated. to confirm that you are passing the form correctly to controller?

Comment: I have had that same problem so many times. You stare at a piece of code for so long and in the end it's a blimming equals sign.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<%= Html.Encode( artist.Name ) %>
```

Note the "equals" and the lack of a closing semicolon.  This is the format used to output the string value to the response.  The other format simply executes the code in the page context, but doesn't automatically write to the response.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me! I knew it would be something stupid :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the `<% some code %>` syntax in ASP.NET translates quite simple to "execute this code".

The `<%= some code %>` syntax in ASP.NET translates to `Response.Write(some code)`.

Based on this, it becomes clear why `<% Html.Encode(...); %>` returns nothing. It's encoding your text, but no one is writing it to the response! With `<%= Html.Encode(...) %>` the ASP.NET compiler turns it into `Response.Write(Html.Encode(...))`, which will obviously write the encoded text to the response.